# Best Practices for converting a Oracle Forms legacy application to Spring framework application & react JS

Tags: reactjs, spring, oracle, spring-boot

We have a legacy application made in Oracle Forms in the front end and Oracle database as the  RDBMS end. Database includes Oralce database with stored procedures and PL/SQL. I want to convert the same into a modern web application with ReactJS and Spring framework.

I would to insight into what the best practices which I should take into consideration while I design the applicaiton.